# Probability density function of a sum of three exponential variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let A,B and C be three random variables with exponential($\lambda$) distribution. Calculate the probabilities P(A> B+C) and P(A+C>B).

I really have no idea how to do that, maybe someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: Are they independent?

Comment: Integrate the joint density over the relevant region. For example, $P(A>B+C) = \iiint_{x > y + z} f_{A, B, C}(x, y, z) \, dx \, dy \, dz$.

Comment: Yes, they are independent. Thanks for that hint!

Comment: @num2333 Evaluate how $B+C=D$ is disributed. Then find out how $A-D$ is distributed.